# How can I embed the data for a .png file inside of a Ruby file?

Tags: ruby, image

My question is about Ruby source files and the ability to store binary data in them.

I know that after `__END__` in a Ruby file, I can put any data there I want file will still work fine.

I can then load that via the `DATA` constant.

Given a file "foobar.png", how could I actually put this data into a file, store this file after the `__END__` comment and then load it again so that I have a "functional" image here?

My idea is to make a single Ruby file, which serves the HTML to a user (and uses Webrick by default when started) and has some small images as well.

Later on, I would like to store multiple .png files in that file eventually, but for now I'd just like to find out how to read the data-stream that should be a .png file.

Comment: While it's doable, this is a really bad idea. The equivalent representation for the .png file will be much larger inside a text file, which is what Ruby scripts are. Also, you have to modify your source just to modify an image. Instead, split your source and data, don't combine them, into a separate Ruby script, and separate PNG files, and load them from disk as needed. That will be plenty fast and will not require editing the code just to add/delete images.

Comment: Alternates would be to redirect the browser to load the appropriate file as a static image served by an "image" (HTTPd) server, or store them in a database as blobs, or the filenames in the database and the images on disk, but whatever, I'd do anything but store the encoded data in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Ruby file is encoded as text, you can't include the data as a binary blob, so you have to encode it somehow. The easiest way to do this is to combine formats. Do something like put a JSON object after `__END__` mapping PNG names to Base64 data. So:

```
require "json"
require "base64"

f = File.open("thiscamefromthescript.png", "wb")

f.write(Base64.decode64(JSON.parse(DATA.read)['some_png']))

__END__
{
  "some_png" : "BASE64ENCODEDIMGAGEHERE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the UNIX way to read binary data is [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). There is the [Base64 module in ruby core](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) that can be smoothly used for this kind of data.

A general usage code sample:

```
require 'base64'

encode = Base64.encode64(File.read('/path/to/my_awesome_picture.jpg') # this will convert picture to ASCII text
decode = Base64.decode64(File.write('/path/to/new_awesome_picture.jpg', encode)) # This will convert
```

NOTE: Didn't actually test the code but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite simply, at least for a single file, although I’m not sure I’d recommend it. The contents of the `DATA` section of your source file (the bit after `__END__`) don’t need to be text, they can be any binary data, and you can put it in place with [`cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29).

The `DATA` constant is just an [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html) object, so you can just call `read` on it to get the data in a string.

Here’s an example using Sinatra to serve an image. (Using Sinatra in some ways makes this more complex since in classic mode Sinatra looks at the data section itself for inline templates, which is why this example uses the modular style).

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class App < Sinatra::Base

  set :image, DATA.read 

  get '/' do
    headers['Content-type'] = 'image/png'
    settings.image
  end

end

App.run!

# make sure there's a newline after __END__
# but only one so you don't add any more data at the
# start of your image file
__END__
```

Next you need to combine this source file with your image file to create your combined file:

```
cat source.rb image.png > combined.rb
```

Then you can run `ruby combined.rb` and the Sinatra server will serve up your image to any requests to its root.

I think an earlier version of Java for Linux was distributed in a self extracting binary that used a technique similar to this – it used a shell script concatenated to the compressed archive, and the script detected the start of the compressed content in the same file and decompressed and wrote out the files.

Combining more than one file this way would be tricky. You would probably need some delimiter to separate them, and since you are dealing with binary data you would need to ensure that your delimiter can’t appear in the actual data. I think the easiest solution would be to base 64 encode them, and use some data format in the data section that your code could parse and decode.

I would question if this is the right way of going about this though. If you are looking at this to make distributing the script easier a better option might be to package everything up into a gem that contained the code and the images.